# How do I scan a document and save it to disk from my Canon PIXMA MP140?

Tags: canon-pixma

Im sorry for the bafflingly stupid question. But the title says it all. I need to scan a document and save it to disk instead of printing it out (isn't that actually COPYING and NOT scanning??).

Please help and sorry for the really dumb question.
I'm obvoiusly not a SuperUser ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found XSane (based on Sane) for Fedora 13:

```
yum install xsane
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a software that is able to access your scanner. I personally use [Photofiltre](http://photofiltre.en.softonic.com/).

[image]

Click on the small blue scanner icon, scan your document and it will appear in Photofiltre. Then save it to disk!

Comment: Do you know of anything similar for linux (Fedora 13)?

Comment: Tried to upvote but idont have the rep yet.

Comment: @Ramy: you can use Gimp (http://www.gimp.org/unix/).